# R - sapply Over Columns, then lappy Over Elements

Tags: r

Likely because I've spent an hour on this, I'm curious if it is possible - I am trying to transform each element of each column in a dataframe, ***where the transformation applied to each element depends upon the mean and standard deviation of the column that the element is in***. I wanted to use nested `lapply` or `sapply` to do this, but ran into some unforeseen issues. My current "solution" (although it does not work as expected) is:

```
scale_variables <- function(dframe, columns) {
    means <- colMeans(dframe[sapply(dframe, is.numeric)])
    sds   <- colSds(as.matrix(dframe[sapply(dframe, is.numeric)]))
    new_dframe <- lapply(seq_along(means), FUN = function(m) {
        sapply(dframe[ , columns], FUN = function(x) {
            sapply(x, FUN = helper_func, means[[m]], sds[m]) 
        }) 
    })
    
    return(new_dframe)
}
```

So, I calculate the column means and SDs beforehand; then, I `seq_along` the index of each mean in `means`, then each of the columns with the first `sapply`, and then each element in the second `sapply`. I get the mean and SD of this particular column using index `m`, then pass the current element, mean, and SD to the helper function to work on.

Running this on the numeric variables in the `iris` dataset yields this monstrosity:

```
'data.frame':   150 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length  : num  -0.898 -1.139 -1.381 -1.501 -1.018 ...
 $ Sepal.Width   : num  -2.83 -3.43 -3.19 -3.31 -2.71 ...
 $ Petal.Length  : num  -5.37 -5.37 -5.49 -5.25 -5.37 ...
 $ Petal.Width   : num  -6.82 -6.82 -6.82 -6.82 -6.82 ...
 $ Sepal.Length.1: num  4.69 4.23 3.77 3.54 4.46 ...
 $ Sepal.Width.1 : num  1.0156 -0.1315 0.3273 0.0979 1.245 ...
 $ Petal.Length.1: num  -3.8 -3.8 -4.03 -3.57 -3.8 ...
 $ Petal.Width.1 : num  -6.56 -6.56 -6.56 -6.56 -6.56 ...
 $ Sepal.Length.2: num  0.76 0.647 0.534 0.477 0.704 ...
 $ Sepal.Width.2 : num  -0.1462 -0.4294 -0.3161 -0.3727 -0.0895 ...
 $ Petal.Length.2: num  -1.34 -1.34 -1.39 -1.28 -1.34 ...
 $ Petal.Width.2 : num  -2.02 -2.02 -2.02 -2.02 -2.02 ...
 $ Sepal.Length.3: num  5.12 4.86 4.59 4.46 4.99 ...
 $ Sepal.Width.3 : num  3.02 2.36 2.62 2.49 3.15 ...
 $ Petal.Length.3: num  0.263 0.263 0.132 0.394 0.263 ...
 $ Petal.Width.3 : num  -1.31 -1.31 -1.31 -1.31 -1.31 ...
```

I assume I am applying each mean in `means` to *each column* of the dataframe in turn, when I only want to use it for elements in the column it refers to, so I'm not sure that nesting `apply` functions in this way will do what I need - but can it be done like this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your `helper_func`, is, but I've made a toy example below

```
helper_func <- function(x,m,sd) (x-m)/sd
```

You can then adjust your `scale_variables()` function like this:

```
scale_variables <- function(dframe, columns) {
  
  means <- apply(dframe[columns],2,mean, na.rm=T)
  sds   <- apply(dframe[columns],2,sd)
  
  sapply(columns, \(col) helper_func(dframe[[col]], m=means[col], sd=sds[col]))
}
```

And call it like this:

```
scale_variables(iris,names(iris)[sapply(iris, is.numeric)])
```

Output: (first 6 of 150 rows)

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length   Petal.Width
1    -0.89767388  1.01560199  -1.33575163 -1.3110521482
2    -1.13920048 -0.13153881  -1.33575163 -1.3110521482
3    -1.38072709  0.32731751  -1.39239929 -1.3110521482
4    -1.50149039  0.09788935  -1.27910398 -1.3110521482
5    -1.01843718  1.24503015  -1.33575163 -1.3110521482
6    -0.53538397  1.93331463  -1.16580868 -1.0486667950
```